# Can HtmlUnit override JavaScript functions?

Tags: java, unit-testing, htmlunit

I have a login form that when submitted returns a page with an error indicating the supplied email address is invalid. The email address is valid.

This may seem like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut, but it appears as if "the page" is ignoring the form input during its validation stage, I have tried using Javascript delays, to ensure that the Javascript has a chance to execute to no avail.

Is it possible to have HtmlUnit override the Javascript method that is validating the email address?

Comment: @FailingCoder thank you for your edit suggestions, however this is not about Javascript, but about HtmlUnit, which is a Java technology :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general this is posssible, e.g. by intercepting the server responses and replace the function (see http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/faq.html#HowToModifyRequestOrResponse).

But in general this sound like a HtmlUnit issue - it will be great if you open a new issue at GitHub including all the details for us to reproduce (and fix).